# Data fetching from backend but not displaying the data in browser in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, postman

I am passing doctor id and want entire data of doctor in return.
It is showing proper output in postman like this.

```
{
    "message": "Doc_id Retrieved Successfully ",
    "data": {
        "appointment_id": 38,
        "doc_id": 20,
        "doc_name": "Raj",
        "doc_speciality": "Dentist",
        "patient_id": 22,
        "patient_name": "fae",
        "select_date": "2020-11-12",
        "select_time": "2:00PM"
    }
}
```

But when printing in console it is showing only id and giving data as null. Like this

```
{Doc_id: "13"}
{message: "Doc_id Retrieved Successfully ", data: null}
data: null
message: "Doc_id Retrieved Successfully "
__proto__: Object
```

Service method:

```
//inserting & Retrieving Doc_id data
addDataToAPI4(regForm) {
  console.log(regForm);
  console.log(regForm.doc_name);
  let dbname = "/AppointmentRegController/getid";
  return this.httpClient.post(`${this.httpURL}` + dbname, regForm);
  
  
  
}
```

.ts file:

```
viewappointment(id) {
    this.details = {
      Doc_id: id,
   
    }
    this.service.addDataToAPI4(this.details).subscribe((response) => {
      this.details = response["data"];
      console.log(this.details);
      
      console.log(response);
      
      // if (response != null) {
      //   console.log(response['data']);

      // } else {
      //   console.log("not found");
      // }
    }
    );
  }
```

Comment: what's there on HTML? Somewhere it should be `{{details}}`

Comment: try this one 

this.details = response.data;
console.log(this.details);

in HTML
<p> {{details}} </p>

Comment: @PankajParkar Yes  i will create that but for checking weather the data is being fetched in console or not I'm printing, once the data comes to console that printing in html file wont be an  issue but my data is showing null in console only...so can u tell me how to print that entire doctor data based on passing doc_id in console ...

Comment: @Hiten response.data is giving error because there is nothing like "data" variable declared. in our case, we were using ["data"] to pass it as array.